# Can keep load balancer after delete service in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I using EKS (k8s managed cluster) and create service with type LoadBalancer. Can i keep my load balancer after delete that service in EKS?

I want to keeping my load balancer for normal operation

Answer (score 0):

Currently, i know one method to keep AWS LB present when i delete svc. That is set `Deletion Protection` in config AWS LB (NLB).
But, after thinking, i realized because EKS services is required for LB work (like LB must forward trafic to node port, if not exist svc, where is node port?)

Comment: additional: If you only update service, old Load Balancer of svc even present :v